# Making a chat bot with Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am trying to build a chat bot with an Arduino that works through the serial port. It sends the stuff to my Mac. I am having lots of problems, bugs, and so on. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Here is my code so far. I know it's not perfect but that's why I am trying to learn.

```
//error responses from 1 to 10
void error11() {
  Serial.println("What do you mean");
}

void error10() {
  Serial.println("I dont understand");
}
void error9() {
  Serial.println("My Programmer didnt give me a response for that please ask another question");
}
void error8() {
  Serial.println("?????");
}
void error7() {
  Serial.println("Huh??");
}
void error6() {
  Serial.println("Can not compute");
}
void error5() {
  Serial.println("Can you say that again");
}
void error4() {
  Serial.println("Im sorry what");
}
void error3() {
  Serial.println("Hmmm what");
}
void error2() {
  Serial.println("What");
}
void error1() {
  Serial.println("Sorry What Did You Say");
}
// greeting responses from 1 to 10
void greeting10() {
  Serial.println("What can i do for you");
}
void greeting9() {
  Serial.println("Yo");
}
void greeting8() {
  Serial.println("Hello Master");
}
void greeting7() {
  Serial.println("Greetings!!");
}
void greeting6() {
  Serial.println("Sup");
}
void greeting5() {
  Serial.println("Hiya");
}
void greeting4() {
  Serial.println("hi");
}
void greeting3() {
  Serial.println("How is it going");
}
void greeting2() {
  Serial.println("What's up");
}
void greeting1() {
  Serial.println("hello Friend");
}
String stringRead;
long randNumber;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  randNumber = random(4);
  if (Serial.available()) {
    stringRead = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    if(stringRead =="hello","Hello","HELLO") {
      greeting8();
      if (Serial.available()) {
        stringRead = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
        if(stringRead =="hi","Hi","HI") {
          greeting4();
        }
      } else {
        error3();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I really want to be able to have a random response from 1 to 10 but I couldn't get that to work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(stringRead =="hello","Hello","HELLO") {`

is not the way to compare multiple items. You need to use [logical OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68fx2f1.aspx):

`if(stringRead =="hello" || stringRead == "Hello" || stringRead == "HELLO") {`

Or you can convert the string to upper case and do just one comparison. See: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToUpperCase